# How to add dynamic text field in input box in react/javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, input, textbox

I would like to know how to add textbox with delete button when plus icon is clicked

I have two textbox key, value in a row with `Add` and `Delete` button, adds the rows and delete the rows.

But for `value` field have a `plus` icon, which should add the text in below image format.

here is my codesandbox,
https://codesandbox.io/embed/strange-hawking-k7nfh

[image: In value textfield,]

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking here. Can you please clarify? Also, what is your attempt to achieve your goal?

Comment: @entiendoNull thanks for reply, when i click on plus icon in `value` text field  should add new textfield like the image